# How to fix "File named 'manifest.json' is missing from archive" error

Tags: microsoft-teams, visual-studio-mac, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Upon importing an application into Microsoft Teams' App Studio, I am presented with this error. How do I go about placing it into archive?

I've created a test application in both VisualStudioMac and VisualStudio(Windows).
I've created an application within 'App Studio' and get presented with: `Error while reading manifest.json: "composeExtensions[0].commands" is required`

I expect the application to be installed. No matter how I recreate it, the output remains the same: `File named 'manifest.json' is missing from archive1`

Comment: Tried reproducing it in VSCode as well, same error.

Comment: Could you please share you app manifest file?

Comment: solved the issue. well not really solved just recreated the application is VSCode.